# Trying to show images from specific disk

Tags: image, laravel

Trying to do this...

My controller

```
public function read(){
     $directory = 'c:\Users\Developer\Pictures';
     $info = [];
     $files = \File::files($directory);
     //$files = Storage::files($directory);

     foreach ($files as $file) {
          $info[] = pathinfo($file);
     }
     //var_dump($info);
     return view('uncataloged.read', compact('info'));
  }
```

My view

```
  @foreach($info as $file)
    <img src="{{$file['dirname']}}{{ $file['basename'] }}" width="220px" height="220px" ><br>
  @endforeach
```

Gettin this error (Google Chrome) **Not allowed to load local resource:**

So what is wrong with my code? or its some kind of security policy...

Ps: Sorry for my bad english :P

Thanks.

**EDIT** dd($info);

```
array:11 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "dirname" => "c:\Users\Developer\Pictures"
    "basename" => "PHP_Logo.png"
    "extension" => "png"
    "filename" => "PHP_Logo"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▶]
  2 => array:4 [▶]
  3 => array:4 [▶]
  4 => array:4 [▶]
  5 => array:4 [▶]
  6 => array:4 [▶]
  7 => array:4 [▶]
  8 => array:4 [▶]
  9 => array:4 [▶]
  10 => array:4 [▶]
]
```

Comment: can you also show the output of the actual $info by replacing your var_dump($info); with a dd($info), then we can see the output before the view, it might be permission issue on the folder/files, pathing issue

Comment: see your trying to access a directory on a users account/local machine etc, but this cannot be done, as you would need to access it on the local current server '/imgs/hshhshs.png' or through a full url 'http://www.site.con/img/etc???'  I beleive?

Comment: Actually i can show the info get 'dirname' , 'filename' , 'extension' but i cant show the image using dirname and filename in <img src="{{$file['dirname']}}{{ $file['basename'] }}" width="220px" height="220px" >

Comment: well the client wants to get a preview from the Directory and in this case im testing with C://Developers/images  getting all the info from the image but i cant display the image

Comment: so in theory the image should be 'c:\Users\Developer\Pictures\PHP_Logo.png' best also check the output but simply doing <p> {{$file['dirname']}}{{ $file['basename'] }}</p>, this should give you a visual of the files being called so you can see if thats an issue as i cannot see a directory separator in {{$file['dirname']}}{{ $file['basename'] }} so this could also be the issue 'c:\Users\Developer\PicturesPHP_Logo.png' notice the end output of 'PicturesPHP_Logo.png'

Comment: and also you wont be able to view a file at the 'c:\Users\Developer\Pictures' as this is a local machine location and browsers servers cannot access, for security, the images need to be on a sever or another external server hope this helps